# Как определить, что программа запущена первый раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, запуск

Помогите, пожалуйста, с вопросом: как определить, что Python программа запущена на компьютере первый раз? Какие есть варианты, кроме как оставлять на компьютере файл, а потом проверять его наличие? 
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Строить [отпечаток компьютера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) и сохранять у себя в базе. Проверять каждый раз при запуске. Ненадежно. Записывать что-нибудь в реестр. Ненадежно. Спрашивать пользователя. Очень ненадежно.

Comment: Чтобы ответить нужно знать цель. Поясните зачем это нужно и тогда будет понятнее, какой вариант вам лучше подойдет.

Comment: А ещё вам стоит определиться, что такое компьютер. Если винду переустановили — это ещё тот же самый компьютер или уже другой? Если заменили материнку, но винду не переустанавливали — тот же или уже нет? Если постепенно со временем заменили процессор, видеокарту, оперативку, перенесли винду на новый жёсткий диск и потом её обновили — [ещё тот же компьютер или уже нет?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%8F)

Comment: При первом запуске, программа должна запрашивать и выводить некоторые данные , но я не хочу чтобы это происходило при каждом запуске.

Comment: Сохраняйте эти данные в файл. Чем не устраивает?

Comment: Спасибо, я понял, что файл это оптимальный вариант. Я хотел узнать про альтернативные варианты, например если программа была удалена и файл тоже, может ли она оставить какой-нибудь более стойкий след.

Comment: Кстати, спасибо 'Эникейщику',  за идею с цифровым отпечатком.